# Show check marks for the hats I've obtained in the full hat rack

Tags: feature-request, winterbash

Would it be possible to link the listing at [hatdash.com](http://hatdash.com) to the site so that hats we *do* have are checked?  Maybe integrate the full listing into our regular profiles adding a link to `show all hats`?

Right now if you wanted to go after all the different hats, you'd have to have a tab open for [hatdash.com](http://hatdash.com) and your profile page open so you could cross-reference which ones you have and which ones you don't have.  Not the best of workflows.